# How spring boot serialized objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I Have an object :

```
public class MoQueryData {
private Map<String,Map<String,MoQuery>> data;

public MoQueryData() {
    data = new HashMap<>();
}

public MoQueryData(Map<String, Map<String, MoQuery>> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Map<String, Map<String, MoQuery>> getData() {
    return data;
}

public List<MoQuery> getDataForAllVendors() {
    return data.values().stream().flatMap(l -> l.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

while using it in the controller like this :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET ,value = "/queries/")
public MoQueryData getMoQueriesData() {
    return moQuery.getData();
}
```

we get the following json

```
 {
    "data": {....},
    "dataForAllVendors": [....]
   }
```

i don't understand why the getDataForAllVendors is being called?
with @JsonIgnore it does not happens but i', still trying to understand what happening under the hood.

Comment: The deserialization is not done by spring, but by a JSON framework, e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). If I had to guess, I would say it uses all `public` methods for deserialization by default. If I remember correctly, Jackson has some logic to detect getters, but since your `getDataForAllVendrs()`-method does not fit their scheme, it is treated as a separate property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `dataForAllVendors` field due to the getter-like named method in your class `getDataForAllVendors()`. Jackson discovers and serializes all accessible fields by default and the getter named method in your class is therefore discovered too. Renaming this method or marking it as ignored will prevent serialization.

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my code. Saved my life. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @Sebastian Brudzinski is correct answer. However, he didn't explain how to mark method as ignored. To do so mark your method with annotation `@JsonIgnore` marks your property or getter method as one to be ignored by Jackson-JSON serialization. So just to summorize the answer - change the method so it doen't look like getter (say rename it to `retrieveDataForAllVendors()`) or mark it with annotation `@JsonIgnore` will resolve your issue

Comment: This is useful information as a comment, thus giving the OP or anyone with edit access to improve the accepted answer. It doesn't have anything new to be posted as an answer.